# Mysql In operator with python format

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

This is my python code:

```
SEARCH_BY_ID_TEMPLATE = "SELECT {columns} FROM {table} WHERE {field} IN (%s) ORDER BY id LIMIT {limit} OFFSET {offset};"
def something()
    if field == 'id':
        search_template = SEARCH_BY_ID_TEMPLATE;
        search_value = search_value.replace("|", ",")
        pattern = "{}".format(search_value)
    query = search_template.format(columns=",".join(columns), field=field, table=table, offset=offset, limit=limit)
    tmp_cursor.execute(query, (pattern,))
```

I am passing multiple value inside key from api hit so,

search_value is comming as (1,2,4,5)
Now when executing :

```
tmp_cursor.execute(query, (pattern,))
```

It throes error.
Question is how do put multiple values inside "IN" operator?

Comment: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET({field}, {CSV values list})`? PS. Do not mix `{xxx}` and `%s`.

Comment: @Akina this is my answer